# YUM error: dbiOpen: dbapi 1 not available

Tags: linux, rpm

```
[root@tux lib]# yum clean all
error: dbiOpen: dbapi 1 not available
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
CRITICAL:yum.main:

Error: rpmdb open failed
```

I have tried following:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/rpm/__db*
rpm --rebuilddb
```

**But no luck** :(

```
[root@tux lib]# yum clean all
error: dbiOpen: dbapi 1 not available
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
CRITICAL:yum.main:

Error: rpmdb open failed
```

I have search all over internet but didn't find solution :(

Answer (score 0):

The dbapi chooses a version of Berkeley DB to use, in this
case db-1.85, which has been obsolete in RPM for more than 10y.

You can see the setting of the macro for dbapi by examining "rpm --showrc"
and can change the value in /usr/lib/rpm/macros (or other macro file).

What version of linux and rpm is this?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I have re-install `rpm` package again with `--force` and it solved issue.